# Conditional expectation on different probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

A random variable Y is defined on probability space $(\Omega , F,P)$.
A new probability measure is defined $P_o$ on  $(\Omega , F)$ by  $P_o:=\int_A YdP $ .Take another random variable X on this new space and G:=a sub-$\sigma$ field of $F$.
How do we define $E[XY|G]$ in this case?

And is it equal to $E_o[X|G]*E[Y|G]$ ?

I know that,
\begin{align}
\int_A YdP &= \int_A E(Y|\mathcal{G})dP 
\end{align}
But this is w.r.t a single probability measure.How will I write this in terms of $XY$?